# VcXrv to connect to X server on vm

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vcxsrv

System: archlinux as a vm on vmware workstation on windows10 host
VcXsrv installed on windows10 host as X-client.

The question is: if I start X server on archlinux, how to use VcXsrv as X-client and connect to X server on archlinux?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure putty to know a X11 redirect is possible and on which screen of the local server had to connect here have my putty config:
[image: putty config]

Comment: Black VcXsrv for me. Steps: startx in archlinux with `DISPLAY=:0.0`, same as your putty config, `Session` with ip of archlinux and `Port` `22`, login, nothing display in VcXsrv. If I do in putty like `dwm`, `dwm` appears in archlinux's console in vmware workstation but still VcXsrv is a black screen. Did I miss something?

Comment: The black window is the root vcxsrv, to let that window not show select the Hide Root Window, that will not appear anymore #edit# that option can be selexted by right click on the vcxsrv tray icon.

Comment: I follow this youtube, pretty same as yours: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Q-CAOo4e1s`. Here I use `archlinux` and `dwm` as window manager, `st` as terminal simulator. I really want to invoke `st` to use as a window like in the video when he invokes `terminal emulator` in the left conner, but how?

Comment: the trick seems to execute the Xlaunch and configure it (there is go next next next without make modification) that operation may create a configuration for a multiple window redirect. After that he invoke the xfce panel, once the panel is open can call all the application are present there. I try out with the gnome 2 panel and it is work, not very beautiful to see but works!

Comment: Did you mean I have to install `xlaunch` and configure something with it? So that I can invoke archlinux's terminal emulator? I'd like to use only `dwm` and `st` and minimal other third packages as possible.

Comment: XLaunch is part of the vcxsrv application, nothing more to install. Anyway the video you post launch xlaunch, but probably does not metter. If you want to run just some application, once you had open the ssh session with the above configuration for putty or with the flag -X from another linux, you had just to write the executable name in the terminal and the window will show up, that's it. If you want back the shell just add & at the end of command I.E. to launch firefox: *firefox &*

Comment: I asked somewhere and know that `VcXSrv` is actually an X-server but I have X-server running inside of my linux vm, here I just want to have an X-client installed on windows10 host and connect to X-server on linux vm. This is the link `https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3531`

Comment: lol, next time please add you want use it in WSL not just as a tag, my answer potentially is right without that detail! , give me some time more then I'll come to an answer for you

Comment: I just want an X window in linux vm and X client on windows10 host.